# Getting the floor value of a number in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, floor

I have a SQLite database with a table containing the scores of some league players in a bowling center. I'm trying to get the average of the Score column for each player ID. The problem with this is I only need the whole part of the average, and it should not be rounded (example: an average of 168.99 should return 168, not 169).

When trying to find something like this on Google, I only found solutions for SQL Server and some others, but not SQLite, so if anyone can help me with this, I'd really appreciate it!

So far, I'm using `ROUND(AVG(s1.Score),2)` and I'm truncating the extra part in my Java program that uses the database by converting it to a String, removing the unwanted part and then casting it to an Integer, but I'd rather do it all in SQL if possible.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can just use cast it to an integer. It will truncate it, which is equivalent to floor.

Comment: `cast(x as int)` is the same as `floor(x)` only if `x >= 0`.

Comment: @Adam: Something like `case when x >= 0 then cast(x as int) when cast(x as int) = x then cast(x as int) else cast(x - 1.0 as int) end` should work even though it is rather ugly. I'd probably try to [add a proper `floor` function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) if I really needed this though.

Comment: @Adam: The quick and simple `cast` is a good solution for `x >= 0` (which should be the case for bowling scores, right?), just be aware where the holes are.

Answer (score 21):

You can use round(value - 0.5) (seen [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/floor-help-td46158.html))

Comment: +1 for completeness.   

This solution would also work, but like the other posted answer, it only works for x >= 0. For instance, floor(-2.8) should return -3, but using your solution, floor((-2.8 - 0.5)) would return -4.

Comment: the answer mentions round, not floor, and it also works for negative values

Comment: it's so weird that even in 2022 mainstream database systems like SQLite are not able to correctly handle super basic things like proper rounding

Comment: strange result for `round(2102.7 * 100 - 0.5)`  that is `210269`

Answer (score 3):

From [version 3.35.0+](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_35_0), you can use the [`floor()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#floor) function to round down the number:

```
SELECT
  floor(10.0),    -- 10
  floor(10.1),    -- 10
  floor(10.5),    -- 10
  floor(10.9999), -- 10
  floor(-10.0),   -- 11
  floor(-10.1),   -- 11
  floor(-10.5),   -- 11
  floor(-10.9999) -- 11
```

Comment: FLOOR() is not a built-in function. It is one of math functions() which require a custom build of SQLite: https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_math_functions

Comment: For modern versions of SQLite, this is the correct answer. Math functions are available by default when possible and do not require a custom build. `floor()` is available on Debian Bookworm and its derivatives and it's also available in the official Windows build.