# mysql - how to count number of records in an hour (datetime) using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Group records by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110341/group-records-by-time)

I have a mysql table that logs web page requests.

I'd like to write a sql that outputs the number of requets per hour.

```
INPUT:
timestamp              browser
-------------------    -------
2012-06-28 15:06:14    chrome
2012-06-28 15:12:15    IE6
2012-06-28 16:32:16    IE7

OUTPUT:
timestamp              count
-------------------    -------
2012-06-28 15:00:00    2
2012-06-28 16:00:00    1
```

I'm guessing my first step would be to 'truncate' the datetime field so that I can do a group-by.  Searching, I have found some examples of rounding the hour, but none to truncate.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110341/group-records-by-time

Comment: That question is not an exact duplicate, it groups by 15 minute intervals.  In addtion, the answers here are also not duplicates, as they use the date_format functions which are not used in answers to the other question...   To merge these, both the questions and answers would need to be modified.

Answer (score 5):

```
select count(no_of_requests) from table group by date(datetime_field) , hour(datetime_field)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try formatting the date with

```
DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H') as formatted_timestamp
```

and then grouping on that formatted_timestamp

Comment: +1 For considering the date too.

Comment: He could use the other suggestion as well but then he'd have to group using both functions;
    group by date(datetimefield), hour(datetimefield)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `ts_table` as your table name and `ts` as your timestamp column name,

```
mysql> select
    ->     addtime( date_format( ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H' ), '00:00:00' ) as 'during'
    ->     , count( date_format( ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H' ) ) as 'visit_count'
    -> from ts_table
    -> group by 'during'
    -> ;
+---------------------+-------------+
| during              | visit_count |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2012-06-28 15:00:00 |           2 |
| 2012-06-28 16:00:00 |           1 |
+---------------------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to group by DATE() and HOUR() functions to get your output.