# Getting the ceil value of a number in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, ceil

So I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129249/getting-the-floor-value-of-a-number-in-sqlite) has a good answer, but I want to round up no matter what, instead of rounding down no matter what. Adding 1 to it before casting int wouldn't work because it would "round" 5.0 into 6.0, for example.

So how should I implement `ceil` in SQLite?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about this?

```
select (case when x = cast(x as int) then cast(x as int)
             else 1 + cast(x as int)
        end)
```

Comment: I know this was a while ago but Gordon I think DomingoR's answer is probably the most succinct here.

Comment: This one (although more verbose than DomingoR's answer) is actually correct.

Comment: This one is the correct approch since it covers all the corner cases. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399937/7594961) is a more readable version.

Answer (score 7):

This will give you the same answer more elegantly:

```
SELECT CAST(x+1-1e-n AS INT);
```

(assuming you won't have a precision greater than **n** decimal points)

Comment: This will not round up as it will work as floor function. If x has decimal part below 0.5 then x+0.5 will not go over the next integer. This, however, will work: `cast(round(x+0.5) as int)`

Comment: The best way is  SELECT CAST(x + 0.9 AS INT);

Comment: @Husseinmahyoub you solution would only work assuming that `x` would only take numbers with at most 1 decimal point.

Comment: nope, this is incorrect.  Try it with x = 1... it'll give you 2

Comment: @Kyle thanks for nothing this. This should definitively work for all cases where where the precision is less than **n**: `SELECT CAST(x+1-1e-n AS INT);`

Comment: Hey guys, why do you say that @Husseinmahyoub answer doesn't work? I'm trying with android sqlite and it's working, even for 4+ decimal points. I'm asking to prevent future bugs

Comment: @Luís Chaves if you try x = 1.01 on his solution, you will get 1 while the solution should be 2.

Comment: Yeah got it! Thanks @DomingoR!

Comment: I'm getting Error: unrecognized token: "1e"

Comment: @HughDarling, the "1e-n" is equivalent to 0.001 (if n=3). Replacing this should work without issues.

Answer (score 0):

using php you can easily:

```
$db->createFunction('ceil', 'ceil', 1);

$db->createFunction('floor', 'floor', 1);

select ceil(\`column`) from table;
```

Comment: Agreed, this doesn't apply to pure SQLite

Comment: Although the language is php what I feel is that @user2812583 has actually proposed a valid solution. You can always create custom functions in SQLite like this but thankfully there are better approaches in this context. Still +1 from me for proposing something alternative.

Answer (score -2):

Some useful answers, I found this solution really easy as well.

```
select round(column+0.5) from table;
```

It will mean you are always rounding up if your original number is < 0.5 or rounding back down if your original number is > 0.5

Comment: It won't work always. Take for example, `CEIL(1) = 1` where `ROUND(1+0.5, 0) = 2` Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54399937/7594961) post

Comment: If x is 0 this will give 1