# CEIL and FLOOR in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, rounding, floor, ceil

What is the cleanest method to find the **ciel** and **floor** of a number in **SQLite**? Unfortunately SQLite only has `ROUND()` function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Formulas

**Ceil :** `cast ( x as int ) + ( x > cast ( x as int ))`

Take integer part of x and add 1 if decimal value is greater than 0

**Floor :** `cast ( x as int ) - ( x < cast ( x as int ))`

Take integer part of x and subtract 1 if decimal value is less than 0

### Examples

**Ceil :** 

`SELECT (cast ( amount as int ) + ( amount > cast ( amount as int ))) AS amount
FROM SALES WHERE id = 128;`

**Floor :**

`SELECT (cast ( amount as int ) - ( amount < cast ( amount as int ))) AS amount
FROM SALES WHERE id = 128;`

I have checked all the corner cases including negative number with MySQL `ceil()` and `floor()` functions.

[image: Test result]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. It doesn't seem to work with Xerial, nor should it, according to the docs: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html *"The operator % outputs the **integer value** of its left operand modulo its right operand"*

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you very much for the comment. There was a big mistake. It was copied from MySQL instead of SQLite. Please check the corrected version.

Comment: One thing to look out for is, that the number ("amount" or "x") must be of type REAL. I had a month from a database and divided it by 3 to get the quarter. Division with 2 integer operands results in an integer in SQLite. So when the month is 2, it evaluates to `0 + (0 > 0)`, so it returns 0 instead of 1.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `ROUND()` to the effect of `CEIL` and `FLOOR` if you add or subtract 0.5 from the number on hand. I like this more, because it's can be more readable.

Expanding on Anees' example :

**Ceil** : `SELECT ROUND(amount+0.5, 0) AS amount FROM SALES WHERE id = 128;`
**Floor** : `SELECT ROUND(amount-0.5, 0) AS amount FROM SALES WHERE id = 128;`

Thanks Anees for the comment below, I didn't think of that corner case either. His solution is more robust.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think of it. But, note that It won't work always. Take for example, `CEIL(1) = 1` where `ROUND(1+0.5, 0) = 2`. It was better though, if the value would not be an integer.

Comment: Ceil and floor with real numbers ≥ 0, try 0.4999999999 instead of 0.5.

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html#ceil

Apparently SQLite does provide ceiling:

```
ceil(X)
ceiling(X)
```

> Return the first representable integer value greater than or equal to X.
> For positive values of X, this routine rounds away from zero. For negative
> values of X, this routine rounds toward zero.

But - sadly, it is not compiled by default - and is only active if the amalgamation is compiled using the `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_MATH_FUNCTIONS` compile-time option.