# SQLite get floor value of an equation

Tags: sqlite, casting

this is a simplified part of my query:

```
select cast(2102.7 * 100000 as integer)
```

the result is `210269999`

I use cast to floor the result and the result should be integer and the value should be `210270000`

Why is this happening?

**Update**

let me ask another way

I have two decimal columns and i want to multiply them and get the floor of the result, for example:

```
1.2 * 2 = 2.4
floor(2.4) = 2

1.2 * 3 = 3.6
floor(3.6) = 3
```

this code works

```
select cast(1.2 * 2 as int)
-------
2

select cast(1.2 * 3 as int)
-------
3
```

SQLite does not have floor function [See](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7129253/3279825). So I am using cast as int. but because of the floating point problems, i cannot get the true floor result for some values, like this

```
select cast(2102.7 * 100000 as int)
-------
210269999
```

I dont want to round up the result. and if i use round function as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24821301/3279825), the same problem occurs for some values.

```
select round(1.2 * 3 - 0.5)
-------
3 (true result)

select round(2102.7 * 100000 - 0.5)
-------
210269999 (false result)
```

How can I get the true floor for any values?

Comment: *Floating point values are approximate*: https://www.sqlite.org/floatingpoint.html

Comment: I know that but how can I get the true value?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/QpUq14mz

Comment: You probably want `round()` instead of a cast.

Comment: I want the floor of multiply. this is ok but not for other values